# Python as CGI web server

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I've got a terrible job to do. I have to revive some really old Python site/system until new one is written. Its a decade old, and relies on ancient way of doing things...CGI.

The 'webpages' start like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import functions
import datetime, time

#Check if logged in
if functions.verifyCookies() == False:
    print("Location: index.py")

#send HTTP Headers
print ("Content-Type: text/html\n")

#Get Email from Cookies
email = functions.getCookieValue('email')
name = functions.getCookieValue('name')
```

I think I need Python 2.4, and the only dependency is some MySQL python driver (as far as I can tell from the imports). Any idea of how to set this thing up?

I'm going for Centos 5 server. How do I set up the CGI serving tho? Do I just install Apache and than give `.py` files the `+x` permissions, or is there something more to it?

Answer (score 0):

A default Apache installation should have a "cgi-bin" directory configured (usually at /var/www/cgi-bin).  Any executable file placed in that directory or its subdirectories will function as a CGI script.

Comment: K, but the .py files are not in cgi-bin. Can they be ran outside of that with just proper permissions?

Comment: If you want to place the .py files somewhere else, you'll need to configure Apache to treat their location as an additional CGI directory.

Comment: Is there a way to configure apache to always execute .py files as cgi, no matter where they are?

Comment: Yes, there is such a way. You could start here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html or google "AddHandler cgi-script".